# Debian: cannot remove symlink in /sys/: operation not permitted

Tags: linux, permissions, rm, sysfs

I ran some commands without completely understanding them while trying to get screen brightness working and now I'm stuck with a nasty symlink in '/sys/class/backlight/asus_laptop' that I am trying to get rid of.

I have tried

```
sudo rm /sys/class/backlight/asus_laptop
sudo rm '/sys/class/backlight/asus_laptop'

su root
rm /sys/class/backlight/asus_laptop
sudo rm /sys/class/backlight/asus_laptop
```

Going right into directory and typing `rm asus_laptop`, changing ownership and using Thunar to try to remove it.

I get

```
rm: cannot remove '/sys/class/backlight/asus_laptop': Operation not permitted
```

Same goes for unlink, rmdir doesn't work, and Thunar fails.

The permissions on it are **lrwxrwxrwx**

How can I remove it?

Comment: It is the permission on the directory, that matters when removing a file. However `/sys` is special, I don't know if you can add or remove files.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[The `sysfs` file system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt), typically mounted on `/sys`, just like [the `/proc` file system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), isn’t a typical file system, it’s a so called *pseudo file system*. It’s actually populated by the kernel and you can’t delete files directly.

So, if the ASUS laptop support isn’t appropriate for you, then you have to ask the kernel to remove it. To do so, remove the corresponding module:

```
sudo rmmod asus-laptop
```

That will remove the relevant `/sys` entry.

Comment: Small note: Some files can be removed, what triggers certain actions. I am not sure which ones are there in sysfs, but e.g. cgroupfs allows creating/removing cgroups with mkdir and rm.

Comment: @allo the distinction is subtle, but cgroupfs as its name suggests is a different file system. sysfs, which is mounted on `/sys`, only supports reads and writes, it doesn’t support deletion.

Comment: @StephenKitt: If I as a kernel module writer wanted to add something to /sys I could very well provide my own directory node that has delete wired up. Create gives me the shivers though. mknod() is a special call after all.

Comment: @Joshua now you’ve got me intrigued — how would you go about that, without mounting a new kernfs (so no `kernfs_create_root`) or any other fs?

Comment: Modules can add arbitrary nodes to sysfs and procfs with their own vfs handlers.

Comment: @Joshua without registering a new file system? I know about `sysfs_create_mount_point` etc.; but how can you register arbitrary `inode_operations` on a node under sysfs without using that?

Comment: There ain't no rule that all nodes in a filesystem have the same vfs operation endpoints. I went wading through the code a long time ago for my master's thesis. It's possible to pull this off, but the unlink() comes from the directory so you have to register a directory node to do it.